# Listview crazy scroll

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview crazy :)
If there are 2 - 3  elements in listview and i try to scroll ON one element the UI becomes strange.
This is a normal image..http://imagebin.org/305932 if i scroll >>> : http://imagebin.org/305930
There are only 2 elements but... i don't know why change the row...

....code removed

Comment: Can you mention how this layout should have been ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read the documentation.

Comment: this is not very clear. do you have an item that disappears when you scroll in the event that your listview contains a small number of elements? can you post the layout that contains the listview?

Comment: do you have an item that disappears when you scroll in the event that your listview contains a small number of elements?..

YES

Comment: What's with the `count` variable that gets decreased in `getView` but never increased? Once it is 0, `getView` will just return `view`.

Comment: count is length of array ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the concept of ViewHolder

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because you are inflating the layout xml file for each row(every time getView is called).

Use the Holder pattern

check this tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder

Comment: no it not that, but still you are right. He should implement the ViewHolder pattern

Comment: I'm mistaken it is because of the findViewById(), right

Comment: unrelated to the described issue.

Comment: My problem is when i scroll my listview DOWN to UP

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with scrolling, use [View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) Pattern.

This will do to things

1. Remove scroll flicker
2. Improve performance of the listview on scrolling.

Comment: i see a row only.... only the flight "roma ciampino" 
i don't see "pisa" flight

this is my code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7261749/